# Removing "say XYZ.PRF:" name in winplotr in Fullprof?

Tags: visualization-software, software-assistance, windows-operating-system, fullprof-suite, winplotr

I am facing difficulty on removing text like XYZ.PRF:, when we run fullprof in External applications in WinPLOTR. Is there some way to remove it?[image]